# PM to AM time difference in PHP

Tags: php

How to properly get hours and minutes if the first input of time is PM and second time is AM. The answer will be 10 hours right but its show 14 hours. Below is my code.

```
$from_time = '8:00 PM';
$to_time = '6:00 AM';
$newfrom_time  = new DateTime($from_time);
$newto_time  = new DateTime($to_time);
$diff = $newto_time->diff($newfrom_time);
$hours_perday = $diff->format("%H"). " Hour/s ".$diff->format("%I"). " Minute/s";
```

Comment: your example above is `6:00 PM`, typo? and when you provide the time, it considers the time today at `6:00 AM` today, not tomorrow, you need to explicitly say that `6:00` means tomorrow morning, you either set the day using `->setDate` or `->modify()` the `to` datetime object

Comment: typo it should be AM

Comment: how to do that? i dont have idea how to set it in the next day sorry.

Comment: if ($newto_time < $newfrom_time) {
 $newto_time->modify('+1 day');
}

Comment: i do like that so they will put 1 day

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are open to an alternative solution using `strtotime()`.

By wrapping `$from_time` and `$to_time` in `strtotime()`, you can very easily modify time.

The below checks whether `$from_time` is larger than `$to_time`. If true, a day will be added to it.

The first part of the output takes uses (int) to extract the whole number.
The last part of the output subtracts the whole number from the original number to get just the decimals then multiplies that by 60 (because 60 minutes in an hour).

```
$from_time = strtotime('8:25 PM');
$to_time = strtotime('6:00 AM');
if ($from_time > $to_time) {
   $time_perday = (($to_time + 86400) - $from_time) / 3600;
} else {
   $time_perday = ($from_time - $to_time) / 3600;
}

echo (int)$time_perday . " hours, " . (($time_perday-(int)$time_perday)*60) . " minutes.";
```

Comment: already solve i use modify + 1 day btw thanks i appreciate the help.